# How do you round time to the nearest but also change the date in a NodaTime adjuster?

Tags: c#, time, rounding, nodatime

I have to round various LocalDateTime and OffsetDateTime objects to the nearest period of time (always minutes). For example, if you are rounding to the nearest 3 minutes, 9:58 would round to 9:57, and 9:59 would round to 10:00.

This can be accomplished pretty easily with an adjuster like this:

```
public static Func<LocalTime, LocalTime> CreateRounder(TimeSpan d) =>
    input =>
    {
        var delta = input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks;
        bool roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;

        if (roundUp)
        {
            var rUpDelta = (d.Ticks - (input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks)) % d.Ticks;
            return input.PlusTicks(rUpDelta);
        }

        return input.PlusTicks(-1 * delta);
    };
```

However, if the *DateTime object is close to midnight, say 23:59, and it gets rounded to midnight, there doesn't appear to be an *easy* way to change the date forward. I considered making a second adjuster to adjust the date forward, but I wouldn't know if I rounded down, or up, or if it did need to be adjusted forward.

Am I missing something?

Edit:
I'm trying to create and use TimeAdjusters in NodaTime that work like the build in ones as defined [here](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.OffsetDateTime.html#NodaTime_OffsetDateTime_With_System_Func_NodaTime_LocalDate_NodaTime_LocalDate__).

If you create one like this

```
public static Func<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> CreateRounder(TimeSpan d) =>
    input =>
    {
        var delta = input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks;
        bool roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;

        if (roundUp)
        {
            var rUpDelta = (d.Ticks - (input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks)) % d.Ticks;
            return input.PlusTicks(rUpDelta);
        }

        return input.PlusTicks(-1 * delta);
    };
```

And use it like this:

```
var ldate1 = new LocalDateTime(2019,5,17,23,59,00);
var rounder = CreateRounder(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
var roundedDate1 = ldate1.With(rounder);
```

You can an error on the 3rd line specifying:

```
Cannot resolve method 'With(System.Func<NodaTime.LocalDateTime,NodaTime.LocalDateTime>)', candidates are:
  NodaTime.OffsetDateTime With(System.Func<NodaTime.LocalDate,NodaTime.LocalDate>) (in struct OffsetDateTime)
  NodaTime.OffsetDateTime With(System.Func<NodaTime.LocalTime,NodaTime.LocalTime>) (in struct OffsetDateTime)
```

Comment: How would you round to the nearest *7* minutes? Is it "minutes since midnight" or "minutes since the hour"?

Comment: But aside from that - if you've got a `Func<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime>` you don't need to call a `With` method - just invoke the delegate: `var roundedDate = rounder(ldate1);`

Comment: @JonSkeet Typically we wouldn't round to something like 7 minutes, we would only do 3, 6, 15, or not at all. We do this so that hours in a day would add up to 2 decimal places without truncation. I didn't even think to just call the delegate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I get you correct, but I would approach this something like this:

```
    public DateTime RoundTime(DateTime input)
    {
        DateTime output = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, input.Hour, 0, 0);
        if(input.Minute % 3 == 1)
        {
            output.AddMinutes(input.Minute - 1);
        }
        else if (input.Minute % 3 == 2)
        {
            output.AddMinutes(input.Minute + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            output.AddMinutes(input.Minute);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

see if this helps

### Edit

Do you have the option to change the whole thing to `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalTime`?
It would be looking like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<LocalTime> localTimes = new List<LocalTime>();
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(23, 57, 25));
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(23, 58, 25));
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(23, 59, 25));
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(11, 57, 25));
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(12, 58, 25));
        localTimes.Add(new LocalTime(15, 59, 25));
        IEnumerable<LocalTime> locals = localTimes.Select(CreateRounder(new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0)));
        foreach (LocalTime t in locals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Hour + ":" + t.Minute + ":" + t.Second);
        }

        List<LocalDateTime> localDateTimes = new List<LocalDateTime>();
        localDateTimes.Add(new LocalDateTime(2019, 5, 20, 23, 58, 25));
        localDateTimes.Add(new LocalDateTime(2019, 5, 20, 23, 59, 25));
        localDateTimes.Add(new LocalDateTime(2019, 5, 20, 11, 42, 25));
        localDateTimes.Add(new LocalDateTime(2019, 5, 20, 5, 58, 25));

        IEnumerable<LocalDateTime> ldt = localDateTimes.Select(CreateDateTimeRounder(new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0)));

        foreach (LocalDateTime t in ldt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Year + "-" + t.Month + "-" + t.Day + " " + t.Hour + ":" + t.Minute + ":" + t.Second);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Func<LocalTime, LocalTime> CreateRounder(TimeSpan d) =>
input =>
{
    var delta = input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks;
    bool roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;

    if (roundUp)
    {
        var rUpDelta = (d.Ticks - (input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks)) % d.Ticks;
        return input.PlusTicks(rUpDelta);
    }

    return input.PlusTicks(-1 * delta);
};

    public static Func<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> CreateDateTimeRounder(TimeSpan d) =>
input =>
{
    var delta = input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks;
    bool roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;

    if (roundUp)
    {
        var rUpDelta = (d.Ticks - (input.TickOfDay % d.Ticks)) % d.Ticks;
        return input.PlusTicks(rUpDelta);
    }

    return input.PlusTicks(-1 * delta);
};
```

The output is as follows:

```
23:57:0
23:57:0
0:0:0
11:57:0
12:57:0
16:0:0
2019-5-20 23:57:0
2019-5-21 0:0:0
2019-5-20 11:42:0
2019-5-20 5:57:0
```

Comment: That isn't using the NodaTime types of LocalDateTime or OffsetDateTime, nor is it using the adjuster concept that NodaTime uses.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Edited my answer

Comment: This might work, but wouldn't be any different than a work around I already have, which is just an extension method to do it. I'm trying to use the .With methods that are available for creating TimeAdjusters like they have already built in that you can read about here: https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.OffsetDateTime.html#NodaTime_OffsetDateTime_With_System_Func_NodaTime_LocalDate_NodaTime_LocalDate__

Comment: I was being too vague in my question and assuming that someone trying to help would just know what I was talking about. Sorry about that. I have updated my question with more detail.

Comment: Based on the last comment from Jon Skeet, this is likely the best way to do it.